# Argument of type 'unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type

Tags: node.js, reactjs, use-state

[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ofsU.png)

```
Argument of type 'unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<IAluno[]>'.
  Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type '(prevState: IAluno[]) => IAluno[]'.  TS2345

    23 |         const response = await api.get('/alunos');
    24 |         console.log(response);
  > 25 |         setAlunos(response.data)
       |                   ^
    26 |         
    27 | 
    28 |     }
```

I'm lost, I can understand where this 'unknown' type came from...

I'm trying to collect some info from an old api that returns a json.

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOKWH.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TS does not **know** what `response` might contain and if `data` is even a property in `response`. It complains about the type of `response.data`.

If you are confident of the response you can use casting using `as` keyword.

```
setAlunos(response.data as IAluno[])
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the response does not have "data" property. Probably it is called differently. Try to console.log(response) and look for the property you are looking for in this object

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the unknown type is the response.data that you are trying to pass in as a parameter at

```
setAlunos(response.data)
```

I would double-check that response.data is what you are expecting or that it exists. For example, does response?.data work?

Comment: I turned with the response and apparently the information I need is on the .data